# Why aren't comparisons factored into Big O calculations?

Tags: c++, algorithm

When you have code:

```
for(int i = 0; i<N; i++)
{
   array[i] += N
}
```

Isn't it comparing the variable i and N every time the loop iterates.  For that matter isn't it adding 1 to i every time the loop iterates as well?

So, isn't this 3 operations per iteration of the loop?

Why do we usually ignore these operations and say that this code is O(n) ?  Does it have something to do with how these operations are using the CPU?

Comment: O(3n) is usually simplified to O(n), the constant is mostly irrelevant when you start doing a lot calculations, what matters is the power of n because it determines the real growth rate.

Comment: ps. there is a bug in the code, you increment the element of the end of the array a lot. You could change this code to array[N] += N*N. That would have O(1)

Comment: We say that algorithm is O(n) to indicate that it is linear solution. O(3n) will consume exactly 3x more cycles than O(n),  but the class of solution is still linear (means execution time is directly proportional to n )

Comment: Just an example: If n = 1 000 000 000, and your computer calculates 1 000 000 records per second, you will calculate it with an O(n) algorithm for 1 000 seconds (= 16 minutes). For O(n^2) it's 1 000 000 000 * 1 000 000 000 = 1 000 000 000 000 000 000. If the next year your computer will become a thousand (!) times faster, you will calculate it for 1 000 000 000 seconds, which is 31.7 years (!).

So it's just for comparing algorithms, where exact amount spent is irrelevant.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Big-O notation does not deal with the actual cost of the operation, but how that cost grows with the size of the problem. To that extent, `O(n)` does not mean that the cost is `n`, but that the cost *grows linearly* with the size of the problem. Whatever the cost is for 100 elements, it will be doubled for 200 and tenfold for 1000. In the same way `O(n^2)` means that the cost grows *quadratically*, so if the size of the problem doubles the cost of the operation quadruples, if the size increases tenfold, the cost grows hundred-fold.

Constants don't really matter here and they are usually factored out. More over, in many analysis the cost is not even expressed on actual time or memory cost, but the cost of other operations. For example, the `std::map::find` function is said to have `O( log N )`, regardless of the key type. The reason is exactly the same: `O( log N )` means that whatever the cost of finding in a map with `N` elements is, it will grow logarithmically.

For a motivating example, consider a rather absurd problem: finding the author of a book from the full book contents, and two implementations. In the first implementation you use a `std::map<std::string, std::string>` where the first `std::string` is the contents of the book and the second the name of the author. The second implementation performs hashing of the contents of the book into an integer and stores that into an unordered `std::vector< std::pair<int, std::string> >`, the `int` being the hash and the `std::string` being the author's name (assume no hash collisions). The cost of finding the author of the book in the map is `O( log N )` and the cost of finding the author in the vector is `O( N )`, which is worse. But, those costs are hiding the complexity of the comparisons, the cost of comparing the whole book contents in the map might be *huge* compared to the cost of comparing the hash, up to the point that a single comparison of the contents of a book might be more expensive than all of the comparisons needed in the vector case.

Big-O notation deals only with how the cost grows with the size of the problem and hides the actual cost of each operation. When analyzing the complexity of an algorithm, the individual costs are *ignored*, but you should still be aware of them, as the Big-O notation does not tell the whole story and the practical cost of running your algorithm will incur in those constant costs that you ignored in the analysis.

Answer (score 6):

Big-O notation can drop all constant factors. Call the comparison, addition and all other overhead of one iteration `c`. The total running time is then `cn`, and `O(cn) = O(n)` when dropping constant factors.

This mathematical trick is used to compare functions which are going to work on large datasets. An algorithm with the time complexity of `O(n^2)` may very well be faster than one with `O(n)` on small datasets (if the constant factor is large on the latter), but small datasets are often handled fast regardless of algorithm. What's interesting is what happens when the dataset grow - will it take ten seconds to search through a billion records or will it take years? This is very much affected by the time complexity.

Answer (score 6):

The definition of Big-O[*]:

For two functions `f`, and `g`, `f(n)` is `O(g(n))` if and only if there exist numbers `M`, `c` such that:

```
for all n > M, |f(n)| <= c * |g(n)|
```

(where `|x|` is the absolute value of `x`).

So from this definition it is easy to see that the function `3*n` is `O(n)`: just take `c = 3` and any positive `M` you please.

Explanations in terms of "rate of growth" are pretty much waffle (or actually, they're the motivation for the above definition), but they might help form an intuitive idea of how Big-O works.

Why allow a constant factor? Why not define that `f` is `O(g)` only if `|f(x)| < |g(x)|` for `n > M`? A couple of reasons - firstly because of the "rate of growth" waffle/motivation: what we're really saying with big-O notation is what happens when you double `n`, triple it, etc. Secondly because the idea of an "operation" isn't clear-cut. Adding 1 to an integer doesn't take the same amount of time as a comparison, or a jump. It doesn't even necessarily take the same number of CPU instructions. So what are you going to measure in? Seconds? CPU cycles? On what CPU, running at what speed, with what bus bandwidth? What if algorithm A is very slightly faster on x86, whereas algorithm B is very slightly faster on ARM? Then would the time of either of them be Big-O(the time of the other one)?

For abstract analysis we need ways to compare algorithms that aren't rooted in any particular hardware, and Big-O is one of those tools.

So, it's irrelevant to the big-O complexity of an algorithm whether it does three constant-time operations per loop, or a million. They still contribute `O(n)` time, just pick a big enough `c`.

If you do `log(n)` operations per loop (looping `n` times) then you're no longer `O(n)`, because for any `c`, eventually `log(n) > c` for big enough `n`. Hence there doesn't exist any `M` and `c` to satisfy the condition. `n * log n` is not `O(n)`.

[*] as it applies to the complexity of an algorithm -- Big-O is also used when approaching limits other than infinity, but we don't care about that.

Comment: [*] It's the same Big-O, just different use cases.

Comment: @Emil: true, it's just that what I've defined here is Big-O as `n -> infinity`. The definition of `f = O(g)` as `n -> a` is that there exist `c`, `e` s.t `|a - n| < e  => |f(n)| < c * |g(n)|`. That's not very interesting for functions of integers!

Answer (score 0):

We are saying that it is proportional to n, as n approaches infinity. So n*(4 operations) to which I don't know how long they take on your processor is proportional to n.

Answer (score 0):

It's not important whether you have the constant factor equal to 2 or 2^10. The most important thing is 'how the execution time will grow compared to the growing n'. Constant factors are droped also due to the fact that code will be optimized by a compiler. You can't be sure that after optimization `c` will be still equal 3.

I would recommend you to get familiar with www.coursera.org `Algorithms: Design and Analysis, Part I` online course. There are several (short) lectures about dropping constant factors and Big O notation.